# why is `sum()` not working with float in `for` loop csv data?

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

i can only use one loop, one `if` statement and i used my only if statement to filter the rows in a csv file to print specific rows with the same job name. so i used a `try` `except` to find the average of the salary income.

to give values inside the `for` loop i used `sum()` to fill up the total_salaries but because the salaries were in float it didn't work. here is the code:

```
for line in reader:
    name, job, salary = line
    salary = float(salary)
    salary = salary + (salary*0.1)
    instructor_count = len(line)
    total_salaries = sum(salary)
```

i tried writing total_salaries = sum(float, salary) but that gave me a type error

here is the full code to get the complete picture:

```
    import csv
    file = open('SP21-Emp1.txt', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    total_salaries = 0
    instructor_count = 0
    print("Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt" "\n")
    for line in reader:
        name, job, salary = line
        salary = float(salary)
        salary = salary + (salary*0.1)
        instructor_count += 1
        total_salaries += salary
        if job == 'Instructor':
        instructor_count += 1
        total_salaries += salary
        first_name, last_name = name.split(' ', 1)
        print(f'Name: {last_name} {first_name} \t Job: {job} \t Income: {salary}',)
    try:
        average_instructor_salary = total_salaries / instructor_count
    except ValueError:
        print('can not calculate average because there were no instructor salaries found.')
        average_instructor_salary = "No instructor salary found"


my output was this:

    Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt
    
    Name: Tweijari Bilal     Job: Instructor     Income: 2200.0
    Name: Hachem Nizar       Job: Instructor     Income: 1980.0
    Name: Saeed Walaa        Job: Instructor     Income: 2090.0
    Name: Khattar Nadine     Job: Instructor     Income: 1628.0
    
    The average of the instructors' salaries is: 1493.8

but if you look at the average for my output and the expected output that is coming up you will see that it is different.

    Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt
    
    Name: Tweijari, Bilal     Job: Instructor     Income: $2200.0
    Name: Hachem, Nizar       Job: Instructor     Income: $1980.0
    Name: Saeed, Walaa        Job: Instructor     Income: $2090.0
    Name: Khattar, Nadine     Job: Instructor     Income: $1628.0
    
    The average of the instructors' salaries is: 1974.5


this is the latest update, i am a certified dumbass, i copyed and pasted the print line in the wrong place... so now i do get a value but it is still not the expected value

    

    import csv
    
    file = open('SP21-Emp1.txt', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    total_salaries = 0
    instructor_count = 0
    print("Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt" "\n")
    for line in reader:
        name, job, salary = line
        salary = float(salary)
        salary = salary + (salary*0.1)
        instructor_count += 1
        total_salaries += salary
        if job == 'Instructor':
            first_name, last_name = name.split(' ', 1)
            print(f'Name: {last_name} {first_name} \t Job: {job} \t Income: {salary}',)
    try:
        average_instructor_salary = total_salaries / instructor_count
        print("\n" "The average of the instructors' salaries is:", average_instructor_salary)
    except ValueError:
        print('can not calculate average because there were no instructor salaries found.')
        average_instructor_salary = "No instructor salary found"
```

Comment: `salary` is only one item, so `sum(salary)` is just going to return salary.  What you want is `total_salaries += salary`.

Comment: great for the fist time i actually got a value, i freaking love u tim...but the answer is different than the expected output. i will edit my post and show the results.

Comment: Same thing applies to `instructor_count = len(line)`.  You just want `instructor_count += 1`.

Comment: the value is now very close but it is still different than the expected value my output is 1493.8 and the expected output is 1974.5. so is my whole equation wrong all this time?

Comment: I cut-and-pasted your exact code, and I get 1974.5.  How are you printing that last line?

Comment: cam you cut and repast the code in the comments because i also just cut and repast the code i wrote here and it didn't give an answer to begin with. maybe i did a mistake without seeing

Comment: I cut and pasted your revised code, and the final output line is `The average of the instructors' salaries is: 1974.5`.

Answer (score 0):

salary is not a list of elements. so sum(salary) will not give a total sum. you can try total_salaries += salary

Comment: i already did now for whatever reason it shows no value. here is the last update of the code

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I'm running, which is an exact copy of your code:

```
import csv
file = open('SP21-Emp1.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
total_salaries = 0
instructor_count = 0
print("Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt" "\n")
for line in reader:
    name, job, salary = line
    salary = float(salary)
    salary = salary + (salary*0.1)
    instructor_count += 1
    total_salaries += salary
    if job == 'Instructor':
        first_name, last_name = name.split(' ', 1)
        print(f'Name: {last_name} {first_name} \t Job: {job} \t Income: {salary}',)
try:
    average_instructor_salary = total_salaries / instructor_count
    print("\n" "The average of the instructors' salaries is:", average_instructor_salary)
except ValueError:
    print('can not calculate average because there were no instructor salaries found.')
    average_instructor_salary = "No instructor salary found"
```

Here is the CSV file I used:

```
C:\tmp>cat SP21-Emp1.txt                                         
Tweijari Bilal,Instructor,2000                                   
Hachem Nizar,Instructor,1800                                     
Saeed Walaa,Instructor,1900                                      
Khattar Nadine,Instructor,1480                                   
                                                                 
C:\tmp>
```

Here is the output I receive:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt

Name: Bilal Tweijari     Job: Instructor         Income: 2200.0
Name: Nizar Hachem       Job: Instructor         Income: 1980.0
Name: Walaa Saeed        Job: Instructor         Income: 2090.0
Name: Nadine Khattar     Job: Instructor         Income: 1628.0

The average of the instructors' salaries is: 1974.5
```

Comment: well my csv file is this, can you please run it again?Adam Saleet,IT Support,1000
Naji Shemmari,Registrar,1250
Bilal Tweijari,Instructor,2000
Abdallah Mazem,Accountant,1000
Nizar Hachem,Instructor,1800
Nawwara Sleiman,Admission,900
Ameen Sinjer,QA Officer,1400
Walaa Saeed,Instructor,1900
Hamid Shami,IT Support,850
Nadine Khattar,Instructor,1480

Comment: i'm an idiot sorry, i just figured out that i was taking in all the data instructors and non instructors, i put everything under the if statement and it worked. thank you very much for all the help. may u have a blessed day